# Handling SQL data in C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

```
namespace iss_farmacie_spitali
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = null;
            DataTable table = null;

            try
            {
                sqlConnection1.Open();
            }

            catch(Exception f)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            sqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user",textBox1.Text);
            sqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass",textBox2.Text);
            sqlCommand1.CommandText = "SELECT id,parola FROM ANGAJAT WHERE id='@user' AND parola='@pass'";

            reader = sqlCommand1.ExecuteReader();
            table.Load(reader);  


            sqlConnection1.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

So i'm trying to do my faithful logon here, but i keep getting the null reference error.
What i need help with is a bit of understanding how to handle the data i get from sql, and how to make it useable as strings and whatnot.

Comment: Where do you get the exception?

Comment: at table.Load(reader);

Comment: where did you create sqlConnection1 and apply connection string ?

Comment: i created the connection and the command in the interface

Comment: I don't see any interface in above code

Comment: I expect whatever it is might be the result of the single quotes around the parameters in your CommandText. You only need to quote string literals, as you're using SQL parameters, the quotes aren't necessary.

Comment: actual graphical interface of visual basic, dragged and dropped them like buttons. i'm not a fan of actual coding

Comment: If you are determined to drag and drop the command and connection objects, then you'll need to both instantiate the data table, and remove the single quotes from your sql query (so both Jon's and Parag's answers should have your solution in them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple problems here.

One is that you haven't shown where `sqlCommand1` or `sqlConnection1` are declared or initialized. My guess is that they're both null, which is why you're getting the exception. They *should* be declared and initialized within the method, using `using` statements so they get disposed appropriately:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new SqlComand(...))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then there's this problem.

```
SELECT id,parola FROM ANGAJAT WHERE id='@user' AND parola='@pass'
```

The fact that you're got quotes means you're looking for an ID of exactly `@user` - not the value of the `@user` parameter. You want:

```
SELECT id,parola FROM ANGAJAT WHERE id=@user AND parola=@pass
```

EDIT: And as noted, initialize your `DataTable` too :)

Comment: My guess is that the original poster has dragged and dropped the connection and command classes onto their form. This leads to multiple instances of the connection object, command etc for each control within the project, making reuse EXTREMELY difficult.

Comment: @user1889231 You'll need to follow Jon's advice for your query, and Parag's advice for instantiating the data table first before using it. That should get your code 'working' but it's not necessarily the best way to do things :-)

Comment: thanks. i'm always looking to make it easiest for me, not actual best, especially in trivial matters, but thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @dash: Ick, that's horrible, yes :(

Comment: @JonSkeet - +1. Good observation about SQL statement. :)

Answer (score 5):

In your code `table` variable has been initialized to `null` so it will throw `NullReferenceException`.

Make following corrections in your code -

1. Initialize `table` variable
2. Initialize SqlConnection & make use of `using` for object cleanup after use
3. Initialize SqlCommand & make use of `using` for object cleanup after use
4. Set `connection string`
5. Make use of `using` for object cleanup after use of `reader`

AS -

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    SqlDataReader reader = null;

    //Corrections
    DataTable table = new DataTable(); //#1 : Initialize Table

    using(SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection()) //#2: Initialize SqlConnection & make use of `using` for object cleanup after use
    using(SqlCommand sqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand()) //#3: Initialize SqlCommand & make use of `using` for object cleanup after use
    {

        sqlConnection1.ConnectionString = "<connection string>"; //#4: Set connection string
        sqlCommand1.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        sqlConnection1.Open();

        sqlCommand1.CommandText = "SELECT id,parola FROM ANGAJAT WHERE id=@user AND parola=@pass";

        sqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user",textBox1.Text);
        sqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass",textBox2.Text);

        using(SqlReader reader = sqlCommand1.ExecuteReader()) //#4 : Make use of `using` for object cleanup after use
        {
            table.Load(reader);  
        }

        sqlConnection1.Close();
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

Summarized corrections to improve asnwer as per [Jon Skeet's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) observations :)

Answer (score 2):

You are not checking if there is any row in the reader or not , thats why you are getting null point exception.

here is the code snippets

```
reader = sqlCommand1.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read()) 
{
   // Do somthing here
}
```

hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words buddy !